# Using the quadratic formula.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may sound a bit basic but when using the quadratic formula working through $\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}$, should I be considering $- 4ac $ or $-(4ac) $? Not sure if this is worded correctly but some feedback would be helpful!

Comment: no it is $$\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

Comment: Either way, $-4ac=-(4ac)$.

Answer (score 3):

Either way it would be correct, in fact they are the same. If you a have an equation of the form $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$ and want to find $x$ then, as the formula shows, you get $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4 ac}}{2a}$$Note that all these constants $a,b,c$ must have their actual sign. For example, consider
$$ - 4x^2 + 2x + 3 = 0$$ then $$x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4\cdot(-4) \cdot3}}{2\cdot (-4)} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{52}}{-8}$$

Comment: Im not sure what i did wrong on this problem that makes sense.  Think its time to sleep!  Thank you